# Can't open folders with spaces

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I have the following code to read items from my FTP-Server:

```
internal List<FtpItem> OpenFolder(string folderName)
{
   FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpWebRequest("ftp://myserver.com", folderName);
   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
   List<FtpItem> ftpItems = GetFtpItemsFromRequest(request);
   return ftpItems;
}

private List<FtpItem> GetFtpItemsFromRequest(FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest)
{
   List<FtpItem> ftpItems = new List<FtpItem>();
   WebResponse webResponse = ftpWebRequest.GetResponse();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
   string line = reader.ReadLine();
   while (line != null)
   {
      ftpItems.Add(new FtpItem(line));
      line = reader.ReadLine();
   }
   reader.Close();
   webResponse.Close();
   return ftpItems;
}   

private FtpWebRequest CreateFtpWebRequest(params string[] url)
{
   FtpWebRequest webRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Join("/", url));
   webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
   webRequest.UseBinary = true;
   webRequest.Credentials = this.networkCredential;
   return webRequest;
}
```

As long as I try to open a folder like `root/sub/subsub` everything works fine. But if the foldername contains a space, I get the error-message

```
No such file or directory
```

I tried to replace the space-character by %20, but this doesn't work.

What do I have to do to open folders which contains spaces?

Comment: Did you try to put the directory name in quotes when it contains spaces?

Comment: I tried it with "ftp://myserver.com/test folder", but this doesn't work

Comment: I mean myserver.com/"test folder", or myserver.com/somefolder/"folder with space"/folder

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it with ftp://myserver.com/Testfolder/"Testfolder Root3"

Comment: At least mention what kind of FTP server you are using.  They are *not* created equal.

Comment: What do you mean with "what kind of FTP server"?

Comment: I tried your code with my FTP server and it runs fine even with folder names with space. I only had to add a closing "/" to the url.

Comment: Side note - you are creating a lot of objects which implement `IDisposable`. They should be wrapped in `using` clauses for proper deterministic release of resources.

Comment: Thanks to StevenHouben: I added a / to the end of the url and now it works.

Comment: You're welcome, I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a closing "/" at the end of your url request. So either append it to the end of the request:

```
FtpWebRequest webRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Join("/", url)+"/");
```

or add an empty string as url parameter:

```
FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpWebRequest("ftp://myserver.com", folderName,"");
```